# What is the art genre of this painting on the T-shirt?

Tags: painting, style-identification

I don't know exactly what the genre of this painting is. It looks nice to me, so I hope I could see more of it from other artist as well.

[image]

Comment: Where did you come across this shirt?

Comment: On Instagram, but I forgot what the username exactly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formally it reminds me of [**art brut**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outsider_art) (or the related [**primitivism**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Na%C3%AFve_art)), because of its somewhat crude and naive style. It *could* also be considered **expressionist**, but it's hard to tell without seeing more art by the artist (and expressionism is a very broad art movement, which might not help you very much).

The texture and colour scheme are slightly reminiscent of [Paul Klee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Klee)'s work, but the artwork you post is more naive and straightforward:

[image: Paul Klee - Abendliche figur - 1935]
<sup>Paul Klee, *Abendliche figur*, 1935. [Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:LaM_Klee_figure_le_soir.JPG).</sup>

The image's content is quite obviously **symbolist**, though: through easily legible symbols and representations we can deduct the artist's (possible) intention.
The main figure has symbols for a sun and a moon behind their left and right hand, respectively, a heart symbol at around the physical location of their heart, and their belly seemingly occupied by the head of another, squatting figure. Green leaves on both sides suggest a presence of and possible synergy with nature.

Since the shirt and the information I found about it online doesn't show an artist, I think this artwork was made by Rob Thomas of Matchbox Twenty himself, as the pieces depicted on other shirts in the Hard Rock Café Signature shirt series [seem](https://www.brassmonkeyvintage.com/product/1994-hard-rock-cafe-signature-series-edition-don-henley-art-t-shirt-l) to have been created by their respective artists, as well.

Art brut or outsider art consists of works of art that are usually created by non-art-educated artists, who lack theoretical, historical, and/or formalistic education.

Comment: Thanks a lot, may you have a great week ahead!